# why bodymovin result animation looks more stretched than the source frames

Tags: animation, after-effects, lottie, bodymovin, webflow

im making an animation of some product that listens to you and reacts accordingly,
however, i want to upload my animation to my webflow project 

my animation resolution is 1080x720, however i export the keyframes as PNG images (like webflow tutorial recomends) and then i import those images inside a new  After Effects project and then i export the animation (I would like to say that I follow each step of the tutorial exactly as it is) but the problem comes when i test my result json inside LottieFiles previewer, the animation looks stretched (i cant explain it so ill upload 2 images to show the problem)

the [original frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccc47.png) is a png image used in the bodymovin sequence

the [json output frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDUH7.jpg) is a base64 image (the first frame of animation) stored in the bodymovin animation result data.json

the two images above are the same resolution but looks diferents, i want to know why and how to fix it

thanks in advance

[link to the original webflow tutorial that i follow](https://youtu.be/hY1a94niwpY?t=1070)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry this was just a problem of configuration, i figured out how to fix this, i just have to set bodymovin settings > assets > "Copy original a Assets" turn on, in fact, bodymovin use a low-level AI that remove the white / transparent padding and expand the content, enabling original Copy forces bodymovin to avoid using that AI